# Thymeleaf + Spring Security Expression language

Tags: spring-security, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm trying to fetch the `UserDetails` object out of Spring Security from Thymeleaf. I have tried various SpEl things, like:

`${#authentication.principal.blahblah}`

I'm trying to assign this to a Javascript variable as:

`var foo="${#authentication.principal.blahblah}";`

I'm using Spring Boot 1.2.5 with the `thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4` dependency declared.

Comment: Have you tried printing out something like this first? `<span sec:authentication="principal.firstName"></span>`.  You can also check this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29758675/spring-security-3-2-7-how-to-access-user-details-by-thymeleaf

Comment: Spring Boot 1.2 uses Spring Security 3 by default, but you're using Thymeleaf's Spring Security 4 integration. That's either going to break things or your question's incomplete as you've done some more configuration that you haven't described.

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
<script th:inline="javascript">
var foo = /*[[${#authentication.principal.blahblah}]]*/;
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just using pattern `/*[[${#authentication.principal.username}]]*/` may occurs NPE like exceptions. So I usually use expression below.

```
/*[# sec:authorize="isAuthenticated()"]*/
const loginUserName = /*[[${#authentication.principal.username}]]*/ 'admin'
/*[/]*/
```